# Upload file jsp and servlets

Tags: jsp, servlets, file-upload

I try to upload a file(image or txt) and i what to show that file in divs or textarea.
I'm using jsp and java servlets.
I'm searching for similar examples but i didn't find, can anyone help me??
Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem i solved with a simple ideea searched. After upload i change the backround src of with ajax and indicate to a servlet that responds   with an blob image. So the image will be in the div background.